# How do you set TargetFramework & TargetFrameworkVersion using Directory.Build.targets (not .props)

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to set **TargetFramework** for SDK style projects and **TargetFrameworkVersion** for legacy projects using Directory.Build.targets.

My understanding is that if I want to *add* a property not already defined by a CSPROJ I use Directory.Build.props. Per the documentation this is imported before MSBuild reads the project file. I should use Directory.Build.targets to *overwrite* properties already specified by the project file.

**Directory.Build.targets**

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework.Contains(net481))' == 'true'">
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion.Contains(v4.8.1))' == 'true'">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This sits in the root of my solution folder. When I build my solution I receive this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Project '..\GenericName.csproj' targets 'net48'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'.    GenericName C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    1830
```

This doesn't have an error code and I can't find any information about the error. Right now all the projects actually have 4.8.1 defined in the project files and I'm trying to downgrade that to 4.8 using the targets file.

I suspect that the condition I am using for the Full Framework Legacy projects is suspect because for SDK style projects the targets file does work properly.

Comment: I'm not clear why you are getting the error message but if it helps the error message is from the `GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask` task which is part of NuGet.

Answer (score 2):

For both legacy style and SDK style projects there is a set of 'project system' files imported. A concern is that given the importance and nature of the `TargetFramework` and `TargetFrameworkVersion` properties, overriding in the `Directory.Build.targets` file may be late for some usages of the properties.

You might consider a different approach.

In `Directory.Build.props` define properties and change the projects to use the properties.

e.g.

```xml
<!-- Directory.Build.props -->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <dotNetTFM>net7.0</dotNetTFM>
    <dotNetFrameworkTFM>net48</dotNetFrameworkTFM>
    <dotNetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</dotNetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

For a legacy style project:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>$(dotNetFrameworkVersion)</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
```

For an SDK style project:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <TargetFramework>$(dotNetFrameworkTFM)</TargetFramework>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...
```

A project that multi-targets may have

```xml
    <TargetFramework>$(dotNetFrameworkTFM);netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

As a one-time effort, change your projects with a 'replace in files'. Going forward, upgrading and downgrading is controlled by the property values.